# jenkins groovy-events-listener-plugin disappear after jenkins restart

Tags: events, jenkins, plugins, groovy

Please help, I have an error with groovy-events-listener-plugin for jenkins. It disappear after jenkins restart. I found some info in logs

```
WARNING: Some health checks are reporting as unhealthy: [plugins : There are 1 failed plugins: groovy-events-listener-plugin]
```

And higher

```
    WARNING: Loading plugin Groovy Events Listener Plugin v1.014 (groovy-events-listener-plugin) failed perhaps due to plugin dependency issues
java.io.IOException: Unable to load org.jenkinsci.plugins.globalEventsPlugin.GlobalEventsPlugin from groovy-events-listener-plugin
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.load(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:515)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:517)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:1090)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/settings/IvySettings
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1336)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1197)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:3313)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:3311)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3288)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:302)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.$getStaticMetaClass(GrapeIvy.groovy)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.<init>(GrapeIvy.groovy:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.getInstance(Grape.java:121)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:159)
    at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:378)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:211)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:213)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.globalEventsPlugin.GlobalEventsPlugin$DescriptorImpl.getScriptReadyToBeExecuted(GlobalEventsPlugin.groovy:170)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.globalEventsPlugin.GlobalEventsPlugin$DescriptorImpl.<init>(GlobalEventsPlugin.groovy:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.globalEventsPlugin.GlobalEventsPlugin.getStaticDescriptor(GlobalEventsPlugin.groovy:62)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.globalEventsPlugin.GlobalEventsPlugin.<clinit>(GlobalEventsPlugin.groovy:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.load(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:509)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:560)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 71 more
```

I thing that the reason of this is incorrect plugin instalation which clean class GlobalEventsPlugin after Jenkins reload.
I found some info in another resources that this plugin requires jdk7 instead of jdk8. Please help if you have the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I need to include libraries to my groovy script manually, using `evaluate(new File(/path/to/script/))`

Comment: but how did you add it ?